# WPF application to communicate with Microsoft Project Server 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, project-server

One of our future requirement at work is to be able to read and write from our WPF application into Microsoft Project Server 2010. We know the fact that Microsoft Project Server 2010 is built on top of Sharepoint(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms504195%28v=office.15%29) so we know that you could be able to do this using Sharepoint programming(please correct me if I am wrong).

Based from searching in StackOverFlow and online we could not able to find any resources on how to communicate with Project Server using our WPF application. Is this really the case for WPF app and Project Server? Or we could be missing something. We recently implemented Exchange Server communication with our WPF app and we thought it will be similar case in terms of Project Server 2010.

(More info: We are using TFS for team collaboration)

Answer (score 0):

True: Project Server is built on top of Sharepoint

Partially Wrong: Data related to Project Server (except some configuration information) can be accessed using SharePoint API calls.

Project Server uses its' own API called PSI: Project Server Interface, ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms512767.aspx)).

The API includes web services (WCF or ASP.NET) to access different data related to project plans, resources, etc. Some information can be accessed through different services, but set of fields in the case could be different: Field A + Field B could be accessed through Web service A, but only Field B could be accessed through Web service B

PSI works according to Security setups on the Project Server and there are required permissions defined for every function of the API.

I said that it is partially wrong that Project Server data can be accessed using SharePoint API. The partial is because you can synchronize your projects with SharePoint lists and in this case the SharePoint lists can be accessed using SharePoint API.